# Accessibility focus order not working as expected [iOS]

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover, becomefirstresponder

**OVERVIEW**
I'm having trouble getting correct focus order (Accessibility in iOS). It seems like  becomeFirstResponder() overwrites my focus order I have specified in the array and causes Voice Over Accessibility functionality to read wrong Accessibility Label first.

**DETAILS:**
I have a View Controller with containerView. Inside I have UIView of my progress bar image and text input field (placeholder). Both elements have *isAccessibilityElement = true* attributes and they have been added to my focus order array. However upon screen launch, focus order goes to the input field instead of progress bar UIView.

After extended testing I've noticed that this issue is no longer replicable if I remove below line of code.

```
 otpNumberTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

But this is not a solution. I need cursor in the textfield but Voice Over functionality to read my Progress Bar Accessibility Label first. How to fix it?

**SPECIFIC SCENARIO**
I've noticed this issue occurs only when I have VC with a last active focus on a Textfield and then transition to the next VC (with a Textfield and a Progress Bar).

Bug is not replicable when I have VC with a last active focus on the Button and then transition to the next VC (with a Textfield and a Progress Bar).

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var otpNumberTextField = UITextField()
    var progressMainDot = UIImageView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        
        setupView()
        setupBinding()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        setupView()
        textFieldDidChange(otpNumberTextField)
    }
    
    func setupView(){
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(named: ColourUtility.BackgroundColour)
        view.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        //Progress Bar
        let progressBarView = UIView()
        containerView.addSubview(progressBarView)
        progressBarView.isAccessibilityElement = true
        progressBarView.accessibilityLabel = "my accessibility label"
        progressBarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        progressMainDot.image = UIImage(named:ImageUtility.progressMain)
        progressMainDot.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        progressBarView.addSubview(progressMainDot)
        
        //Text Field
        otpNumberTextField.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.none
        otpNumberTextField.font = UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: FontUtility.inputLargeTextFieldStyle)
        otpNumberTextField.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        otpNumberTextField.isAccessibilityElement = true
        otpNumberTextField.accessibilityLabel = AccessibilityUtility.enterVerificationCode
        otpNumberTextField.placeholder = StringUtility.otpPlaceholder
        otpNumberTextField.textColor = UIColor.init(named: ColourUtility.TextfieldColour)
        otpNumberTextField.textAlignment = .center
        otpNumberTextField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        otpNumberTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        containerView.addSubview(otpNumberTextField)
        otpNumberTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        
        //Accessibility - focus order
        view.accessibilityElements = [progressBarView, otpNumberTextField]
    }
      
    //... more code goes here ...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have already set `accessibilityElements`, then voice over should respects that order but calling `becomeFirstResponder()` changes the focus to that text field.

You can try below code, which notifies voice over for shifting the focus to new element due to layout changes.

```
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .layoutChanged, argument: progressBarView)
```

So now your modified method should be like below:

```
func setupView(){
    .....
    otpNumberTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

    //Accessibility - focus order
    view.accessibilityElements = [progressBarView, otpNumberTextField]
            
    UIAccessibility.post(notification: .layoutChanged, argument: progressBarView)

    .....
}
```

Comment: Om Prakash I've tried this before but solution seems to be buggy. When I used below code, VoiceOver still starts to read the InputTextfield first and only after a while it switches and starts to read my progress bar. I currently have a workaround implemented to hide TextField from Voice over 'otpNumberTextField.accessibilityElementsHidden = true' and then use function to unhide it after 5 sec. That way VoiceOver starts reading the progress bar first. Also note this bug occurs only when previous VC was focused on another input field (does not occur for VC which last active focus was on button).